# Prove or disprove:Integrating a Vector Function along a Continuous Differentiable Curve

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $(f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2)$ be defined as $(f(x, y) = (y, x)^t)$, and let $(\gamma: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2)$ be a continuously differentiable curve with $(\gamma(0) = \gamma(1))$. Then it holds that

$
\int_{0}^{1} \langle f(\gamma(x)), D_x\gamma(x) \rangle \, dx = 2\pi.
$

To verify the given statement, let's consider the integral again:

$
\int_{0}^{1} \langle f(\gamma(x)), \frac{{d\gamma(x)}}{{dx}} \rangle \, dx.
$

According to the definition of $(f(x, y) = (y, x))$, we have $(f(\gamma(x)) = (\gamma_2(x), \gamma_1(x))).$

$(Dx\gamma(x))$ denotes the derivative of $(\gamma(x))$ with respect to $(x)$. The integral can be rewritten as:

$
\int_{0}^{1} (\gamma_2(x) \frac{{d\gamma_1(x)}}{{dx}} + \gamma_1(x) \frac{{d\gamma_2(x)}}{{dx}}) \, dx.
$

This can be further simplified as:

$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{{d(\gamma_2(x) \gamma_1(x))}}{{dx}} \, dx.
$

By applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get:

$
(\gamma_2(1) \gamma_1(1)) - (\gamma_2(0) \gamma_1(0)).
$

Since $(\gamma(0) = \gamma(1))$, we have $(\gamma_2(1) = \gamma_2(0))$ and $(\gamma_1(1) = \gamma_1(0))$. Thus, the expression becomes:

$
\gamma_2(1) \gamma_1(1) - \gamma_2(0) \gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0) \gamma_1(0) - \gamma_2(0) \gamma_1(0) = 0.
$

Hence, the integral $(\int_{0}^{1} \langle f(\gamma(x)), \frac{{d\gamma(x)}}{{dx}} \rangle \, dx)$ evaluates to $0$.Which means that the statement is false.

Comment: You are right, however I think the question meant to map $f(x,y) = (-y,x)$ then its right.

Comment: Yes, the line integral is zero. Note that $(y,x)$ is a conservative field: $\nabla(xy)=(y,x)$

Comment: Are you aware that $x, y$ are  not the only variables? Thus you do not need to use "$x$" to serve as *both* the first coordinate of pairs in $\Bbb R^2$ and as the index variable of the curve $\gamma$ in the same context. Poor $x$ is tired of having to pull double-shifts while other variables like $t, r, s$ lie around doing nothing.